# Can't interact on mobile with overflow:auto element underneath scrollable section using fullpage.js, scrollOverflow:true

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js, iscroll

I'm using fullpage.js with scrollOverflow: true. Within a section that requires scrolling, as the section is over 100vh, I have a table that is designed for the user to scroll some content on the x axis.

[image]

Though the scrolling this table works on desktop even at a mobile resolution, scrolling this table on a mobile device does not work at all. The table does not respond to any touch interaction.

This seems to have something to do with the .fp-scrollable div that wraps the scrollable fullpage section. If I add pointer-events: none to .fp-scrollable, I can interact with the table on a touch device, but then the section is no longer scrollable. It is also interesting to notice that text within the .fp-scrollable div cannot be highlighted on mobile or desktop. This seems like a clue, but I'm not really sure what it means.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the fullPage.js option `normalScrollElements`. Check [the docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) for more info.

> **normalScrollElements:** (default `null`) If you want to avoid the auto scroll when scrolling over some elements, this is the option you need to use. (useful for maps, scrolling divs etc.) It requires a string with the jQuery selectors for those elements. (For example: `normalScrollElements: '#element1, .element2'`). This option should not be applied to any section/slide element itself.

Comment: Thanks @Alvaro, this does not seem to work in conjunction with scrollOverflow: true, however. I referenced this pen to set it up: http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/786/, but this does not use the scrollOverflow option.  On my site in which scrollOverflow is used, adding this option, as well as tweaking normalScrollElementTouchThreshold has been ineffective. Again I think this has to do with the .fp-scrollable div covering the elements that need to be scrolled separately from the fullpage sections.

Comment: It probably is a bug of [iScroll.js](http://iscrolljs.com/). I would encourage you to get rid of scrolloverflow and use a real responsive site by using the responsive options and `fp-auto-height-responsive` when necessary.